# Get notified by any change on DefaultComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have two `JComboBox` with the same `DefaultComboBoxModel`, when i want to add/remove an element i use the correct methods `addElement` and `removeElementAt` and the two `JComboBox` are correctly updated, but i want to be notified that the model has changed, is there any tricks to be notified by the `DefaultComboBoxModel` ?

Comment: [`ListDataListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataListener.html) ... also, you're going to have issues with the selected item, as that information is contained within the model itself...

Comment: The `addListDataListener(...)` method is easily found in the [DefaultComboBoxModel's API entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html). This is where you should start for such questions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The two methods are just two examples, DefaultComboBoxModel has a lot of others methods who operate on the model, and i don't want to override all model methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I forgot that DefaultComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel which has the addListDataListener, Thanks so much you saved me ;)

Comment: Naruto, even if you forget, the API lists the methods of the class and all methods of all super classes. Tis a wonderful thing, the API. Glad you've got things moving along.